# rsync (but also other commands) run with nohup gets sigterm

Tags: nohup, hp-ux, sigterm

I'm connecting from my computer to a HP UX B.11.31 system and am running some very lengthy there commands using nohup so I can go to sleep and do something else for a few days while they complete.

Example of such a command:

```
nohup rsync --rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync -e ssh /data/src usr@target:/data/ >> /data/log/sync.out 2>&1 &
```

Note: the Rsync command's target is a different HP UX server.

It'll run and run, until my computer somehow gets disconnected from the HP UX system (it's connected through SSH over a VPN over my home connection, and disconnections seem to happen once a day).

If this has happened, I can `tail /data/log/sync.out` and I'll find:

```
Killed by signal 1.
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at rsync.c(549) [sender=3.0.8]
```

Someone suggested putting the command in a shell script and running that with nohup instead.

So I did that (with a shebang for `#!/usr/bin/bash`), and then ran the command as `nohup ./auto_rsync.sh > /data/log/sync.out 2>&1 &`.

The same thing happened.

The funny thing is that if I simply log out while the command is running by typing `exit`, the command will keep running. So why is only my disconnect sending SIGTERMs to a process running with nohup?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You wonder why `rsync` dies when your connection disappears?

Comment: the connection is between two servers that are definitely up, not between my local computer and the server

Comment: maybe there is a cron script or similar that kills processes that have run for "too long"?

Comment: nope, because when I am not disconnected the process just runs on and on and on and

Comment: What makes you think it's specifically the disconnection of your SSH connection that makes `rsync` fail, as opposed to something causing both your SSH connection and the rsync-over-SSH connection between the two servers to fail at the same time?

Comment: Because it not only happens with rsync commands. It's also any other command that takes a long time. I can't be sure that it happens when I disconnect, but I notice it happens sometime between being connected and me finding out I'm no longer connected. The disconnect event seems the most likely cause.

Comment: @bluppfisk non sequitur -- that cron or whatever script may skip processes run by "logged in" users (those it can find with `who` or `w`). Are you the admin on that server? Can you contact the admin?

Comment: I can contact the admin but they have no idea either why this is happening. So I end up on stackexchange.

Comment: If your client is based on systemd it may be the configuration setting that kills all the user's processes when they log out. On most distributions now it's disabled by default but in 2019 it so it was still quite common

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked on HP/UX but ssh should still have a ServerAliveInterval option. So add "-o ServerAliveInterval=60" after ssh in your command. Or this option can be made perm in .ssh/config or added to the system ssh config file.

*EDIT*

It is called something different on HP/UX. I found some documentation.

https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c01892997

The following parameters, specified in /etc/opt/ssh/sshd_config, allow for setting the desired inactivity period allowed before the session is terminated.

ClientAliveInterval 300
ClientAliveCountMax 6

The above would send a client alive message every five minutes (300 seconds) and for a maximum of six tries. After 30 minutes of a non-responsive client, the client would be disconnected.

The ClientAliveInterval default value of 0 ensures that this alive interval is disabled by default.

Comment: thank you for digging this up. However, the problem is not my getting disconnected, it's that a SIGTERM seems to be sent to processes currently running (although not to the shell script itself). The funny part is also that if I manually log out, everything keeps on running smoothly.

Comment: You should probably be posting errors that you are seeing in "/var/adm/messages" or other logging locations. If the script is running for a while without issues then there is probably something else on the system that is causing the sigterm and not rsync.

Comment: yes; it's not just rsync but any long-lasting command that will eventually terminate around the time I get disconnected. I probably should've chosen another command as an example.